# How to add delay between API calls in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

EDIT: I'm using java 8 so can't use executor to add delay.

I have to call an API multiple times to get a set of data. I do it using CompletableFuture as given below.Here I'm actually calling the method that calls the said API (`getStockConversionResponse`).

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutureList = hbbConnectionDetail.stream().map(connectionDetail -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getStockConversionResponse(connectionDetail, finalTeamLead, finalReceivePmsId), configuration.stockConversionExecutor()).thenAccept(stockDetailsList::add)).collect(Collectors.toList());

CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutureList.size()])).get();
```

But the issue is, their backend cannot handle all the requests at once, so some requests fail. So they asked to do API calls with 1 second delay between each call.

How can I add 1 second delay between each call here?

Comment: use a timer: https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask

Comment: By specifying an executor, you can control the maximum number of concurrent connections, e.g. via thread pool. The one second delay is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Besides that, the code would be simpler if you use `toArray` on the Stream in the first place, instead of collecting into a list and calling `toArray` on the list. Further, when you chain `stockDetailsList::add` to an asynchronous operation, you have to ensure that `stockDetailsList` is thread safe.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the reply. Executor method is available from java 9, I'm using java 8. Is there any other suggestions please? Also thatks for the advice on list issue

Comment: I’m referring to the possibility to [specify an `Executor` to `supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) which can be combined with a lot of possibilities, e.g. [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxConcurrentRequests)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)…

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [circuit breaker](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker) from the excellent [Resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j) library. Essentially you wrap all remote API call into a circuit breaker, where you specify how many times a call should be retried and how long to wait in-between retries.

[Example](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j#circuitbreaker-retry-fallback) for their documentation:

```
// Create a CircuitBreaker (use default configuration)
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = CircuitBreaker.ofDefaults("backendName");

// Create a Retry with at most 3 retries and a fixed time interval between retries of 500ms
Retry retry = Retry.ofDefaults("backendName");

// Decorate your call to BackendService.doSomething() with a CircuitBreaker
Supplier<String> decoratedSupplier = CircuitBreaker
    .decorateSupplier(circuitBreaker, backendService::doSomething);

// Decorate your call with automatic retry
decoratedSupplier = Retry
    .decorateSupplier(retry, decoratedSupplier);

// Execute the decorated supplier and recover from any exception
String result = Try.ofSupplier(decoratedSupplier)
    .recover(throwable -> "Hello from Recovery").get();
```